# Using String's ReplaceAll with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

How to **repalace** the following **String** combination:
*word1="word2"*
With the following **String** combination:
*word1="word3"*

Using *word boundaries* `\b`.

I used the following, but did't work:

```
String word2 = "word2";
String word3 = "word3";
String oldLine = "word1=\"" + word2 + "\"";
String newLine = "word1=\"" + word3 + "\"";
String lineToReplace = "\\b" + oldLine + "\\b";
String changedCont = cont.replaceAll(lineToReplace, newLine);
```

Where `cont` is a **String** that contains a lot of characters including *word1="word2"* **String** combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last `\b`. It will not do what you think, `"` is not a word character.

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "alma word1=\"word2\"";
String replacement = "word1=\"word3\"";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\bword1=\\\"word2\\\"", replaceMent);
```

Comment: Double quotes are nothing special in regex, so you don't need to escape them - ie `"\\bword1=\"word2\""` is preferable

Comment: @jabal jabal ma yehezzak ri7 :D

Comment: @jabal Sorry about that, but I thought you knew Arabic, where jabal in Arabic means mountain, and there's a famous proverb that says: "Oh mountain, never be shaken against any wind" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your `lineToReplace` line by this:

```
String lineToReplace = "\\b" + oldLine + "(?!\\w)";
```

It should work the way you want.

Comment: `(?=\W|$)` can also be written as `(?!\w)`, or in this case just `\B`.

Comment: Thanks @Qtax: Updated the answer with simpler `(?!\\w)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have word boundaries \b inside your string (the ") and you are using word boundaries in your regexp . Remove that last \b for example.

Comment: +1 for reminding me that I had a word boundaries `\b`  inside my **String** already, which is the `"`

Answer (score 0):

The only word boundary you need is at the front - the rest of your match already has word boundaries built in (the quotes etc).

This will work:

```
 cont.replaceAll("\\bword1=\"word2\"", "word1=\"word3\"");
```